# What the php caches that support tagging?

Tags: php, caching, memcached, apc

**I need a cache system for PHP that suport tags.**

It's will be used caching a lot of queries results, from many users, and every time I will need to clear some user cache, or some module cache...

I thinked, and conclude that tagging are the best way to do that.

Like ('messages_unread_user_300','messages','user_300','unread') it easy to clearup when needed.

I've tried xcache and apc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "tagging" in this context?

Comment: @Pekka: probably for 'remove by tagname' etc., i.e. most caches are straight key=> value pairs, while you might want related data updated or destroyed based on some common denominator. If I need something like that I usually define a 'taglist' as just another key=>value (array) pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memcached wiki has a solution that looks like it may fit yours:

http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgrammingTricks#Namespacing

See "Deleting By Namespace"